# Define Task Queue Handler in Google Endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, task-queue

I am using Google Endpoint in Python.
Now I want to add a push queue but I do not want anyone has the right to trigger this queue. 
For example, I create a queue when user call one api.

> `endpoints.method(..,path='conference',http_method='POST',name='createConference')
>   def createConference(self, request):
>       ...
>       taskqueue.add(url="/task/sendEmail", params={"conference": conference})`
>       ...
>   Now, how can I define the handler for this queue and nobody can call it by api?
>   I got stuck here several days, please give me some hints for guiding me to be out here.
>   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Endpoints method can be protected by [restricting the users that can call the API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth#Adding_a_user_check_to_methods)

```
endpoints.get_current_user()
```

For restricting direct call to push-queue, [Google's Push Queue doc says](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_URL_endpoints), "You can prevent users from accessing URLs of tasks by restricting access to administrator accounts. Task queues can access admin-only URLs. You can restrict a URL by adding login: admin to the handler configuration in app.yaml."

app.yaml snippet

```
handlers:
- url: /tasks/process
  script: process.app
  login: admin
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question, how can I define a handler which can respond to the url defined in taskqueue?

Comment: I found one solution for above question by using "webapp2". [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push). But I still can not find solution by just using "endpoint"

Comment: what do you mean by "respond to the url defined in taskqueue"?

Comment: If your original question is answered, I'd suggest you should mark this one 'accepted' and start a new thread for the new one. That will help people looking for your original question here and those looking for the new one at the new thread.